# How to call if condition if only one array is empty if both empty then call else condition?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am getting the response from model and display on the controller.

**Model**

```
//some code here
return array('secondary_data'=> $result,'primary_data' =>$result2);// sending to controller
// some code here
```

**Controller**

```
$result=$this->Search_model->get_search_name($cust_name);//calling model    
$data['secondary_data'] = $result['secondary_data'];
$data['primary_data'] = $result['primary_data'];

print_r($data['secondary_data']);
print_r($data['primary_data']);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member_id] => 
            [customer_id] => 
            [first_name] => qwer
            [last_name] => poiu
            [email] => 
            [member_type] => 2

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member_id] => 1
            [customer_id] => 0011
            [first_name] => asdasd 
            [last_name] => asdasda
            [email] => bappyang68@gmail.com
            [member_type] => 1

        )

)
```

but sometimes I am getting empty array of `print_r($data['primary_data'])` because of no data. Yes, it's possible.;

but in below if condition I am checking the data count `count($data) > 0` and if found empty then calling the else part.

**I don't want to call else part if only one array is emply. if both array is empty then it should call else part**

```
    if (count($data) > 0)
     {
        $data['title'] = "Search";
        $data['heading'] = "Search";
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('search',$data,true);
        $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$data);
        }
       else{
       echo "NO data available";
      }
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks

Comment: if(count($data) && (!empty($data['secondary_data']) || !empty($data['primary_data']))){...}else{...}

Comment: write `condition for both array` or Use `loop` and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your both array separately in or condition

```
if (count($data['primary_data']) > 0 || count($data['secondary_data']) > 0)
{
   $data['title'] = "Search";
   $data['heading'] = "Search";
   $data['content'] = $this->load->view('search',$data,true);
   $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$data);
}else{
   echo "NO data available";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition with OR operator

```
if(!empty($data['primary_data']) || !empty($data['secondary_data'])){
//One or both array have values
}else{
//Both have no values
}
```

Comment: Your code is also working for me. upvote from my side

Comment: This is short and simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate condition for both array, If one of them is not empty then apply If condition otherwise else.

```
if ( !empty($data['secondary_data']) || !empty($data['primary_data']) ) {
    $data['title'] = "Search";
    $data['heading'] = "Search";
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('search',$data,true);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/dashboard',$data);
} else {
   echo "NO data available";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start checking from $data then sub array

```
if(count($data) && (isset($data['secondary_data']) && !empty($data['secondary_data'])) || (isset($data['primary_data']) && !empty($data['primary_data']))){
      ....
    }else{
      ...
    }
```